# Error installing deluge on ubuntu server (unmet dependencies)

Tags: server, ppa, dependencies, deluge

I am getting the error that I have an unmet dependency "deluge-common" when I run the command:

```
dprogers@homeserver:~$ sudo apt-get install deluged    
[sudo] password for dprogers:     
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory    
WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'share' for parameter 'security'    
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree           
Reading state information... Done    
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have    
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable    
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:    
The following packages have unmet dependencies.    
 deluged : Depends: deluge-common (= 1.3.11-0~trusty~ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have added the deluge ppa but still no luck beyond adding this I am at a loss for what to do. How can I get this to install?

If it helps here are my ppa's:

```
dprogers@homeserver:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://plex.r.worldssl.net/PlexMediaServer/ubuntu-repo lucid main
deb http://plex.r.worldssl.net/PlexMediaServer/ubuntu-repo lucid main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/surfernsk/internet-software/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/surfernsk/internet-software/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: Please add the full error message and also what have you tried so far to solve the problem so that we can think from different angles.